# How to force boot time chkdsk to show progress in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk

How do I force a boot-time chkdsk to show progress, like they did in Windows 7? I want to make sure it is running (and to stare at the data).

Comment: Windows often boot up slowly -- I thought it was hanging.  So I hit the reset button and it started up quickly again.  But it must have been trying to scan the disk!  I'm not happy about discovering this, and not happy with all of the other draconian things Microsoft is doing in Windows 10 (forced upgrades, computer turns on in middle of night because it thinks it shouldn't be off.)

Comment: absolutely annoying and dangerous. They prefer us doing a hardreset when it stucks at W logo than showing us checkdisk progress! For W7 it can be tweaked using `msconfig`'s Boot tab activating `No-gui boot` and `OS boot information`. Let's see how it works on next auto-checkdisk on boot.

Comment: @JaredThirsk Windows can have a slow boot for a variety of reasons, most of which can be solved by booting to WinRE and deleting `hiberfil.sys` and `pagefile.sys` within the root of the system partition. If the PC has had a dirty shutdown [hard reset], it's best to reboot Windows from the Login screen, as a dirty shutdown sets a specific flag that will not be cleared until the OS has been correctly rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Barakando's answer: to create a full disk check, you need to use the `/f` flag to `CHKDSK`, as it is documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk).

As such a check requires the disk to be detached (un-mounted), because it manipulates the low-level filesystem data structures on way, which is incompatible with its usage. It tries to detach the disk. If it can't be done, then the full disk check will happen on the next reboot.

This was yet more verbose on Win7, but in Win10 the verbosity was simply disabled by the Microsoft, because they love us all and don't want to make our life too complex.

Probably there is no way to make it more verbose. At least not a way what can be find by google. Possibly booting into a rescue system or live system, and then making the scan from the command line would work.

However, the scan results are logged and you can get the results with the command

```
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"}| ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | fl timecreated, message
```

Or the text log with the command

```
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"}| ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | fl timecreated, message | out-file Desktop\CHKDSKResults.txt
```

As written [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b154f313-298e-432f-a0e2-e4f4cc993c12/see-status-of-chkdsk-on-reboot-in-real-time-on-windows-10?forum=win10itprogeneral).

Answer (score -1):

Open command-prompt as Administrator (right-click on the start button to do that).
In the command prompt, type in the following:

```
CHKDSK /f /r /x C:
```

It will prompt you to restart - do that.
You will see CHKDSK running, with progress, on boot.

Comment: I did this (on a non-C: local hard disk drive) and it just closed all existing file handles and started scanning the disk.  Is there a way to force it to do it at boot time?

Comment: This is completely useless.

Comment: No, it is not completely useless - it happens only if the `C:` can not be umounted because some locks.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Please do not make an edit that adds content not in the original question/answer, as that's an attempt to reply and should not be done; instead, please either post the additional content in a comment or create an answer.

Comment: @JW0914 I improved the post, particularly about the now deleted comments, if you disagree post improvements, please read more the meta sites.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Editing a post is not for adding content not already in the post and you should know this since it's a preset rejection reason for edit approvals for users <2000 rep

Comment: @JW0914 I can not have any other advice to you than reading the metas more.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Please link to the meta that states explicitly this is a proper edit, as edits like yours are routinely rejected daily for "_**attempt to reply:**
This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer._" ([Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/rygY4P7)). The entire purpose of your edit is an attempt to reply and I have flagged the answer for moderation intervention

Comment: @JW0914 I did not reply, I improved the post.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, after thinking, digging and trying, a this time essentially different answer was born.